# Make Thunderbird fully portable

Tags: thunderbird

I downloaded and installed Thunderbird in a specific folder(non default, using tar). I set the `--profile` argument to point the profile to a specific folder. Also created a a new profile and set as default using `about:profiles`

Even after this still creates a folder in the home directory `.thunderbird` that contains `Crash Reports`, `Pending Pins` etc.

Can Thunderbird be set fully portable ?, not set anything in home folder.

Comment: downloaded what specifically and installed it, how?

Comment: I edit profiles.ini to new path and old profile after first start of Thunderbird. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder I used to be able to do this same thing with Firefox, but that does not work anymore, even if not using Snap.

Comment: @oldfred I can move the profile folder, but the profile.ini that points to the  new folder and other config folders, cache etc are still created in home; if I delete the home config will not know where the profile is, so is not really portable because configs are still in home folder

Comment: @MarcusMüller download as an archive and unpack in a folder

Comment: archive? from where? I'm really confused now, @user3541631!

Comment: @MarcusMüller from thunderbird website, I downloaded the software as *.tar.bz2

Comment: @user3541631 ah thanks!